# Parse user/metadata/runtime data from cloudformation into EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, metadata, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to setup my windows 2016 instances in cloudformation stack and It requires some inputs from user that is taken in parameter section to be transferred into the instance and the software inside would require those parameters. Till now i only found that i can send it by parsing it inside a powershell script while saving the data into a text file. Is there anyother method? or more efficient method to do this???

Answer (score 0):

See [Bootstrapping AWS CloudFormation Windows Stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-windows-stacks-bootstrapping.html).

In short, you typically use [AWS::CloudFormation::Init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html) metadata and [`cfn-init`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-init.html) in `UserData` to bootstrap and initialize your instances.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an AWS CloudFormation template that can take a parameter from the CloudFormation stack and put that information onto the Windows instance:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  Username:
    Type: String
    Description: Ask for a username, will be placed on the instance

  WindowsAmiId:
      Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
      Default: /aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base

  KeyName:
    Type: String
    Description: Keyname for the keypair to use when launching EC2 instances

Resources:

  AppInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      ImageId: !Ref WindowsAmiId
      InstanceType: t2.large
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          <powershell>
          Set-Content -Path 'C:\username.txt' -Value '${Username}'
          </powershell>
```

The result is a file in `C:\username.txt` that contains the `Username` parameter that was provided when the stack was launched.

Alternatively, you could call `describe-stack` to retrieve the parameters.